# How to get text by Selenium and Python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem in getting text from Html by Selenium and Python

inerHtml

```html
<span data-select="" data-selected="Selected" data-deselect="Press enter to remove" class="multiselect__option"><span>ONE</span></span> <!---->
<span data-select="" data-selected="Selected" data-deselect="Press enter to remove" class="multiselect__option"><span>TWO</span></span> <!---->
<span data-select="" data-selected="Selected" data-deselect="Press enter to remove" class="multiselect__option"><span>THREE</span></span> <!---->
```

I want to take the text.

Try:

```
a.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'span > span').text
```

but I failed.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: sorry.  It seems to be because of the special nature of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
a.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "multiselect__option").text
```